# Why returned value from AJAX disappears almost instantly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

this is my server-side code:

**modify_emp.php**

```
<?php
    echo $_POST[id];
?>
```

And this is my Javascript in my html page:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

  var alreadyClicked = false;

  $('.element').hover( 
    //mouseenter function
    function(){
        $('.element').click(
            function(){
            $(this).css("color","blue");
            var objName = $(this).attr('name');
            var objColumn = $(this).attr('id');
            if(!alreadyClicked){
                alreadyClicked = true;
                $(this)
                .prepend('<form method="POST" class="newInput"><input type="text" name="newInput" style="width:140px"></input></form>');
                var elemento = $(".newInput");
                var position = elemento.position();
                $(".newInput").css({
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'top': position.top + 15,
                    'opacity':0.9,
                    'z-index':5000,
                })
                .focus();
                //on enter keypress
                $(document).keypress(function(e) {
                    if(e.which == 13) {

                        $.ajax({

                            url: 'modify_imp.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: { id : objName, column : objColumn },
                            success: function(data, status){
                                $("#debug").html(data);
                            }

                        });
                    }
                });
             } //if (!alreadyClicked) end
        }); //end mouseenter function
   },
   //mouseleave function
   function () {
    alreadyClicked = false;
    $(this).css("color","red");
    $(".newInput").remove();
   }
 ); //end .hover
```

});

The `debug` is a `<div id="debug"> </div>` at the end of my html page where i want to show my response from server. When i press 'ENTER' I can actually see the value for 0.1s inside that div, but then it disappears.

I already tried to pass the return value to a local or global variable but it didn't work.
For some reason the value inside `response` is lost after 0.1s, even if i pass it to another variable elsewhere.

Can someone explain me why and how can i "store" the server response?

EDIT: Just edited with my entire `<script>`

Comment: `return` is a reserved word. try `reservedData`

Comment: Yeah sorry it's not 'return' in my actual code, i just traslated in english my code so you can understand better. I don't think that's the problem. I just changed it with 'response'.

Comment: You're setting a click handler inside the hover handler. This means it keeps adding more copies of the click handler every time you move the mouse over the element. So after you mouseover for the 10th time, there will be 10 copies of the click handler; when you click, it will try to run all that stuff 10 times, except that most of it will only run once because `alreadyClicked` will be `true`. This uses up a small amount of memory and processor power unnecessarily. The click handler should be set outside the hover handler; the hover handler can be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you see the result momentarily, I'm going to hazard a guess that you have a form element on your page and when you hit return, it's actually submitting the form.  You briefly see the result of the ajax operation and then your form submits causing the page to reload as a new blank page.  This is a common issue and always has these same symptoms.

You can either remove the form element or block the default submission of the form with javascript.

If you show us more of your actual HTML, we could help more specifically with how to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Yes that code is related to a form! I need the form element, so how can I "block the default submission of the form"?

Comment: @Notash - show us the relevant HTML please.  You can create an `onsubmit` handler for the form and return `false` from that.

Comment: i just edited my main post with my entire javascript, the form is created dinamically under the clicked element

Comment: @Notash - you need to create an onsubmit handler for your form object.  You can either specific it in your HTML or you can find the `<form>` object after inserting it and attach an event listener or you can change the way you create the `<form>` object so you can attach the listener directly to it right when you create it.

Comment: Ok returning false from a function in "onsubmit= " solved my problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by calling the function in the form tag i.e,

`<form action="javascript:AnyFunction();">`

your code goes here

.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to assign a BUTTON to trigger the ajax, and set the button outside of the FORM